# Dominance ordering on partitions of $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, integer-partitions

Denote the collection of partitions of $n$ by $\mathcal{P}(n)$, with the property that for $\lambda = (\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_s)\in\mathcal{P}(n)$ we have
$$\lambda_1\geq \cdots \geq \lambda_s \geq 1,\qquad \lambda_1+\cdots +\lambda_s =n$$
Then we define a partial order on $\mathcal{P}(n)$, denoted $\geq $, by taking for $\lambda,\mu \in \mathcal{P}(n)$ where $\lambda$ is as above, and $\mu = (\mu_1,\cdots,\mu_t)$:
$$\lambda \geq \mu \iff \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i \geq \sum_{i=1}^k \mu_i \quad \text{for} \,\, 1\leq k \leq \text{min}(s,t).$$

Are $(5,2,1,1,1,1)$ and $(3,3,3,2)$ incomparable? We have $\text{min}(s,t)= 4$ and $n=11$:

\begin{array}{c|c}
k& \text{sum up to k for }\lambda \text{ and }\mu\\
k=1 & 5> 3\\
k=2& 7>6\\
k=3& 8<9\\
k=4& 9<11\\
\end{array}

It seems so. Am I understanding this dominance ordering correctly? I think then I have this top one, dominant over both of the below. But the below are incomparable.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\blacksquare&\blacksquare&\blacksquare&\blacksquare&\blacksquare\\\hline 
\blacksquare&\blacksquare&\blacksquare&\\\hline
\blacksquare&\blacksquare\\\hline
\blacksquare\\\hline
\\\hline
\\\hline
\end{array} $$
Is dominant over both of these:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\blacksquare&\blacksquare&\blacksquare&\blacksquare&\blacksquare\\\hline 
\blacksquare&\blacksquare&&\\\hline
\blacksquare\\\hline
\blacksquare\\\hline
\blacksquare\\\hline
\blacksquare\\\hline
\end{array} \qquad\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\blacksquare&\blacksquare&\blacksquare&\color{white}{\blacksquare}&\color{white}{\blacksquare}\\\hline 
\blacksquare&\blacksquare&\blacksquare&\\\hline
\blacksquare&\blacksquare&\blacksquare\\\hline
\blacksquare&\blacksquare\\\hline
\\\hline
\\\hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: Yes, you are getting everything right; they are incomparable.

Comment: And $(5,3,2,1)$ dominates both $(5,2,1,1,1)$ and $(3,3,3,2)$.